# Brackets-Shell install package dependencies and Grunt ERROR

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, brackets-shell

I am trying to setup Brackets-Shell on Windows 7. I run `npm install -g grunt-cli` and it works with no errors, but then I run `npm install` and it gives me the following error message:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.9
3 info using node@v0.10.28
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
6 verbose install where, deps [ 'C:\\Users\\Alexander\\Documents\\GitHub\\brackets-shell',
6 verbose install   [ 'grunt',
6 verbose install     'grunt-cli',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-jshint',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-copy',
6 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-clean',
6 verbose install     'guid',
6 verbose install     'grunt-curl',
6 verbose install     'grunt-shell',
6 verbose install     'q',
6 verbose install     'semver' ] ]
7 info preinstall Brackets-Shell@0.41.0-0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info Brackets-Shell@0.41.0-0 Failed to exec preinstall script
10 error Brackets-Shell@0.41.0-0 preinstall: `bash -c 'mv appshell.gyp .appshell.gyp'`
10 error Exit status 1
11 error Failed at the Brackets-Shell@0.41.0-0 preinstall script.
11 error This is most likely a problem with the Brackets-Shell package,
11 error not with npm itself.
11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11 error     bash -c 'mv appshell.gyp .appshell.gyp'
11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls Brackets-Shell
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
14 error cwd C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\GitHub\brackets-shell
15 error node -v v0.10.28
16 error npm -v 1.4.9
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong! Btw, I'm following this guide: https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-Brackets-Shell. I followed the same guide on my macbook and it worked with sudo.